# ManyToMany association with same JPA entity(self join) with auxiliary table with additional columns

Tags: database, hibernate, jpa, db2, hibernate-mapping

I am creating an entity `Document` which points to `T_DOCUMENT` table. A document record can have a `ManyToMany` relationship with another `Document`. This relationship is maintained in an auxiliary table `T_DOCUMENT_DOCUMENT`. The structure of `T_DOCUMENT_DOCUMENT` table is below

```
id      |document_batch_id|document_parent_id |document_child_id|document_linker_user_id|creation_time             |modification_time         |
--------------------------|-------------------------------------|-----------------------|--------------------------|--------------------------|
   1    |25               |          500000000|        458000000|              200000002|2020-08-18-12.11.35.026608|2020-08-18-12.11.35.026608|
   2    |25               |          500000000|        458000001|              200000003|2020-08-19-08.27.42.853620|2020-08-19-08.27.42.853620|
   3    |25               |          458000001|        458000002|              200000003|2020-08-19-08.29.49.497022|2020-08-19-08.29.49.497022|
   4    |25               |          500000001|        458000001|              200000003|2020-08-19-08.29.50.030971|2020-08-19-08.29.50.030971|


id = autoincrement primary key of the table 
document_batch_id  = foreign key from another `DOCUMENT_BATCH` table 
document_parent_id = foreign key from `Document` 
document_child_id  = foreign key from `Document`
document_linker_user_id = foreign key from `DOCUMENT_USER` of the user who created this document link
creation_time = timestamp when record is inserted. Value updated by database trigger
modification_time = timestamp when record is updated. Value updated by database trigger
```

It's important to note that this link between documents doesn't have to be created while inserting a new document object. It can be linked later on by the user.

I can achieve this functionality by simply creating another `DocumentJoinDocument` entity which manages the table itself, but I was wondering if there is a way to achieve this only using the `Document` entity.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If there's just one extra column, there are tricks you can use to achieve that. For more than one column - I'm afraid you're out of luck

Comment: What is the trick for just one extra column ?

Comment: See an example [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/JPA/0320__JPA_ElementCollection_MapKeyEntity.htm). Actually, I just realized you could probably also use an `Embeddable` as the map value, possibly allowing for multiple columns. Not sure if that's supported, though, you'll need to check

Comment: I did think about `Embeddable ` initially, however, in my case the join table has, it's own primary key. @Embeddable must not have a primary key. I guess in this case I will have to settle for a new `DoccumentJoinDocument` entity. Thanks for your advice though.